# Где ошибка в моем условии при работе с ответом сервера android?

Tags: android, строки, if, null

У меня приложение создано как сервис для общения, люди могут мне слать письма и я им могу тоже слать, есть так же черновики. Вот я сейчас хочу сделать так как в приложении Gmail, чтобы новые сообщения выделялись жирным. Но ведь мне нужно чтобы выделение было только у новых входящих сообщений, а не у всех новых писем. В ответе с сервера стоит индикатор возле каждого из сообщений, новое оно или нет. Я эту переменную вытаскиваю из ответа, и теперь я пытаюсь сделать так: если сообщение новое и оно входящие то выделить тему, дату и текст письма. Вот какая у меня была проверка на новизну:

```
Integer new_one = message.getNewField();
if (new_one == 1) {
holder.tvSubject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
holder.tvDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
holder.tvFrom.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
}
```

все как-бы работает, но любое новое сообщение отмечается жиром: входящее, исходящее и черновики. Поэтому я думаю что нужно как-то проверять что письмо именно входящее, а не какое-то другое. У меня с ответа сервера тянется имя отправителя или получателя, это два разных метода, но у обоих на выходе есть строка, вот я подумал что можно проверять - если эта строка не пустая то значит делаем жир, а если пустая, то жир у сообщения не делать. Вот как я попробовал сделать:

```
if (new_one == 1) {
if (!message.getSender_name().isEmpty()) {
holder.tvSubject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
holder.tvDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
holder.tvFrom.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
}
}
```

но я получил ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
```

эта ошибка указывает на строку:
`if (!message.getSender_name().isEmpty())`

походу я что-то не так сделал, и поэтому у меня вылетает эта ошибка. Очень надеюсь, что вы мне поможете решить эту проблему.

Comment: Самый простой способ проверить в чем дело: брейк на том месте и посмотреть, что приходит в ``getSender_name()``.

Comment: И зачем вы смешиваете ``стильВерблюда`` и ``стиль_змейки`` в одном имени?

Comment: вот мне уже не первый раз говорят что нужно поставить брейк и посмотреть что да как, но я честно говоря так и не нашел как и куда его поставить)

Comment: что значит смешиваю?

Comment: У вас метод называется getSender_name. В этом имени смешаны два способа именования - через заглавную букву и через подчеркивание. Не запрещено, но плохой стиль.

Comment: а как можно тогда его назвать? я просто делал класс-модель в сервисе и там так назвало

Comment: Про отладку: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/basic.php

Comment: getSenderName(). [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: так я вроде нашел где посмотреть про эту точку, но куда там дальше смотреть нужно? это я так понял где-то должно показаться что пришло?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте проверку на `null`

```
 if (message.getSender_name() != null && !message.getSender_name().isEmpty()) {
              ....
    }
```

Comment: это мне обернуть эту проверку которая есть сейчас, еще этой проверкой что вы предлагаете?

Comment: нет. замените свою проверку на эту

Comment: а как мне на новизну проверку внедрить, ну то есть у вас сейчас проверка есть только на наличие имени, а мне еще нужно будет походу прилепить и свое условие

Comment: у Вас есть проверка `if (!message.getSender_name().isEmpty())`, замените ее на `if (message.getSender_name() != null && !message.getSender_name().isEmpty())`

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, скорее всего здесь достаточно проверки на `null`. Сервер не будет Вам присылать пустую строку - это неправильно и не логично. Он вообще это поле не пришлёт, если оно не нужно. Но если сомневаетесь, то проверяйте. А чтобы выражение не резало глаз можно применить метод [`TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) - он включает обе проверки.

Comment: @woesss, что значит "чтобы выражение не резало глаз", я вот перешел по вашей ссылке, но честно говоря не очень понял как юзать то что вы дали. Эту строку можно вставить в условие вместо того что у меня есть?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, Вы можете написать условие так: `if (new_one == 1 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message.getSender_name())) {` . _чтобы выражение не резало глаз_ - имеется в виду короче и читать проще.